# Django-require - how to load a module before another

Tags: python, django, datatables, requirejs, load

I'm working with django-require and i need to import in my html page Datatables and Datatables Responsive (that is a datatables's plugin for making it more responsive).
The problem here is that when i set all the paths to datatables.js and datatables.responsive.js the final js have an error that blocks all the scripts in the page. Basically i think thats because datatables.responsive needs to be loaded BEFORE datatables, because datatables references a function that is in datatables.responsive.

Actually my common.js file is something like this:

```
requirejs.config({
baseUrl: '../static/js',
paths: {
    "app" : 'app',
    "jquery" : '../jquery/dist/jquery.min',
    "datatables-responsive" : '../datatables.net-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive',
    "datatables" : '../datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables',
    },
shim: {
    "datatables-responsive" : ['jquery'],
    "datatables" : ['datatables-responsive'],
    }
});
```

I tried to make datatables-responsive a dependency of datatables but this isn't working. Any ideas?

PS: if i import ONLY datatables without datatables-responsive it works normally without errors or other problems

Comment: What version of datatables are you using? It appears to me that the current version is AMD compliant and therefore should not need to be shimmed.

Comment: Hi, i'm using the latest version of datatables and datatables responsive. Thanks to your comment i started searching the right things and i found the problem. i'll post the solution in a minute, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem, or better, the *problems*.
Datatables is already an AMD module and dont needs to be shimmed, so using it alone wasn't a problem, the problem was another: *datatables responsive*. In my research i didn't found **ANYTHING** mentioning that datatables responsive requires datatables in a particular way. In my requirejs configuration i was loading datatables with the name "datatables", but when you load datatables responsive, in its code requires "*datatables.net*". **THIS was the problem**. Datatables don't need to be shimmed, neither datatables responsive, no dependency or other things, just define them. Must say that datatables responsive also requires jQuery under the name of "*jquery*". Just look at the code below to understand the right way to import them:

```
requirejs.config({
    paths: {
        "jquery" : './path/to/jquery/dist/jquery',
        "datatables.responsive" : './path/to/datatables.net-responsive/js/dataTables.responsive',
        "datatables.net" : './path/to/datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables',
    },
});
```

then in your init file (or whatever you called it) you will import them like so:

```
define(['jquery','datatables.net','datatables.responsive'], function($, datatables) {

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#datatable').DataTable( {
            responsive: true,
        });
    });

});
```

**FINISH!** Now you have a fully working datatables with the require extension (probably this works also including other plugins).
Hope this helps someone, and sorry for any english mistakes, i'm italian.

Comment: Grazie per la condivisione la vostra soluzione. How is my Italian?  (Your english is fine.)

Comment: thanks, your italian isn't that bad, but the right sentence would be "Grazie per aver condiviso la vostra soluzione" :)